# How to get NavController reference inside onOptionsItemSelected in android

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer project with multiple pages(fragments) which works fine when each navigation item clicks.

Now I want to add options menu as **settings** and **about us**(which are not nav drawer items but options menu items, added at the right end corner 3 dots options).

I was using navigation actions and was very flexible in calling them using 
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_to_about); where ever i wanted.

But now I wanna create a fragment and want to add navigation action to that so that I can call that inside onOptionItemSelected handler but inside onOptionsSelected I don't know how to get a view to findNavcontroller, which can call new navigation action.

after opening the new fragment it should look exactly the same as other navigation item fragments with action bar and name(about us) on it and nav drawer on left swipe.
Suggestions would be a great help.

package com.dave.fluke;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.dave.fluke.ui.AboutFragment;
import com.dave.fluke.ui.RandomGenHomeFragment;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import DB.DBHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    DBHelper randomDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        randomDatabase = new DBHelper(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_randomGen, R.id.nav_flipCoin, R.id.nav_dice, R.id.nav_roulette, R.id.nav_cardPicker, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_about) {
            //I want to open new fragment here
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9MIo.png)

Comment: please paste some code to help

Comment: There is not much code apart from default generated code. In short i want the same navigation style we have in navigation drawer with options items using fragment. I don't want to open new activity on option item click. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

The [Navigate to a destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) goes through many ways to get access to the NavController, including the [`NavHostFragment.findNavController(Fragment)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment.html#findNavController(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) method, which lets you get your NavController from anywhere in your Fragment.

Comment: I have multiple fragments in my project but only one activity. Inside onOptionsItemSelected method I want to open specific fragment in the same way as we click on navigation drawer item.

Comment: There's also [documentation on hooking up menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer), which point out how you can use `onNavDestinationSelected` instead of checking for the `getItemId()` yourself.